# 3D plot of a triple integral in polar coordinates

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, graphics3d

I have a triple integral with 2 changing angles (a and t). I need to integrate it and obtain a 3DPlot in polar coordinates (R,a,t). But Mathematica does not make it. What is wrong here?

```
s = 3;
n = 1;
p = 1;
r = 1;
L = Sqrt[(4*p + r^2)/3];
b = Sqrt[2*n*p];
R[a_, t_] := NIntegrate[((k^2)*Exp[-1.5*k^2])*((u^2)*(1 - u^2)*Exp[-(b*u)^2]*
  (Cos[s*k*u*Cos[a]/L]))*((Cos[c])^2)*(Cos[k*Sqrt[1 - u^2]*
  (s*Sin[a]*Cos[t]*Cos[c] + s*Sin[a]*Sin[t]*Sin[c])/L]), 
  {k, 0, Infinity}, {u, -1, 1}, {c, 0, 2*Pi}]

Plot3D[R[a, t]*B, {a, 0, 2*Pi}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, PolarAxes -> True, 
  PolarGridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"a", "R", "t"}, 
  ImageSize -> 500]
```

Comment: What is `B` in your `Plot3D` command? It isn't defined in your code snippet.  Also, note that `PolarAxes` and `PolarGridLines` are not valid options for `Plot3D`.

Comment: Actually, wait;  what do you mean by a "3D plot in polar coordinates"?  Can you give us an example of such a plot?  There's the `SphericalPlot3D` function, but you wouldn't be plotting your two angles from 0 to 2π if that's what you were trying to do.

Comment: Also note that your integral over `k` can be performed analytically. If you do that and feed the result into `NIntegrate` to do the `u` and `c` integrals, it'll save you some computer cycles.

Comment: If you implement all the hints given by @Michael and amend the  AxesLabel -> {"a", "t", "R"}, you'll get (as I did) a  nice 3D output

Comment: @Andreas:  As did I.  Takes a bit of time, though.

Comment: B is just a coefficient. No, I cannot solve the integral for k, because, this variable is also in the third integral. Yes, you are right, I need a spherical plot. 
B = ((6*sqrt(6)*(b^3))/(erf(b)*(pi^2)))*(1-(3/(2*b^2))*(1-((2*b*exp(-b^2))/(erf(b)*sqrt(pi)))))^(-1);

Comment: My calculation is too long. What time did it take from you?

Answer (score 4):

A few notes:

- In your triple integral, the integral over `k` can be solved analytically.  Note that your integrand is basically of the form
  $$
  X e^{-3k^2/2} k^2 \cos (Y k) \cos (Z k) = \frac{X}{2} e^{-3k^2/2} k^2 \left[ \cos ((Y-Z) k) + \cos (Y+Z) k \right]
  $$
  where $X, Y, Z$ are quantities that are independent of $k$.  Mathematica can do the integral of this quantity from $k = 0$ to $\infty$;  it takes about half a minute but does arrive at a result:$$
  \frac{1}{18} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{6}} e^{-\frac{1}{6} (Y+Z)^2} \left(-(Y+Z)^2-e^{\frac{2 Y
     Z}{3}} \left((Y-Z)^2-3\right)+3\right)
  $$
  Doing this integral analytically allows you to reduce your numerical integral from three dimensions down to two, which leads to a *huge* speedup in the amount of time required to calculate each point.
- In your original code, `B` is not defined.  You'll need to actually define it to get a plot;  the argument to plotting functions must always return a number (not a symbolic quantity) when it's evaluated at points in the plotting range.  In what's below, I have simply set `B = 1`, but you can define it as you wish.
- `PolarAxes` and `PolarGridLines` are not valid options for `Plot3D`.  To create a spherical plot in 3D, you need to use the function `SphericalPlot3D` instead.  If `a` is your "polar" angle and `t` is your "azimuthal" angle, then you want to issue the command `SphericalPlot3D[(*function*), a, t]`

#### Revised code

The code below takes about three minutes to yield the plot at the end.

```
kintegr[u_, c_, a_, t_] = 
          Integrate[((k^2)*Exp[-3*k^2/2])*((u^2)*(1 - u^2)*
          Exp[-(b*u)^2]*(Cos[s*k*u*Cos[a]/L]))*((Cos[c])^2)
          *(Cos [k*Sqrt[1 - u^2]*(s*Sin[a]*Cos[t]*Cos[c]+s*Sin[a]*Sin[t]*Sin[c])/L]), {k, 0, Infinity}, 
          Assumptions -> {-1 <= u <= 1, 0 <= c <= 2 Pi, 0 <= a <= Pi, 0 <= t <= 2 Pi}]
R2[a_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := 
          NIntegrate[kintegr[u, c, a, t], {u, -1, 1}, {c, 0, 2*Pi}]
SphericalPlot3D[R2[a, t], a, t]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you much, but it is interesting, because in my case the process starts and is going to long and does not finish. Now it took 15 minutes and is still going on. I am not sure that it will be finished at all.

Comment: the integrand within NIntegrate doesn't match the defined function kintegr...

Comment: I wrote your code and obtained just an empty frame for a plot and no graph.

Comment: takes about 200sec on Apple M1

Comment: @Hexe:  I had a small typo in the code which I've now fixed.  Try running it again.  Also note that you'll need to do run your own code first (everything up to the `Plot3D` command) before my code will work.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Still there is a typo in the definition of `R2`: It should be `kintegr` not `integr` I think.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann:  Dangit, how'd I miss that?  Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Comments break the code formatting. So I put the code into this answer:

```
s = 3; n = 1; p = 1; r = 1; L = Sqrt[(4*p + r^2)/3]; b = Sqrt[2*n*p];
kintegr[u_, c_, a_, t_] = 
Integrate[((k^2)*Exp[-3*k^2/2])*((u^2)*(1 - u^2)*
Exp[-(b*u)^2]*(Cos[s*k*u*Cos[a]/L]))*((Cos[c])^2)*
(Cos[k*Sqrt[1 - u^2]*(s*Sin[a]*Cos[t]*Cos[c] + s*Sin[a]*Sin[t]*Sin[c])/L]),
{k, 0, Infinity}, 
Assumptions -> {-1 <= u <= 1, 0 <= c <= 2 Pi, 0 <= a <= Pi, 0 <= t <= 2 Pi}]
R2[a_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[kintegr[u, c, a, t], {u, -1, 1}, {c, 0, 2*Pi}]
SphericalPlot3D[R2[a, t] 10., a, t]
```

with B set to 10.
The credit goes to Michael...

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works great ;)